# Using 1st[N] characters when checking for duplicate

Tags: uniq

I have a set of Data in file:

```
AAAPOL.0001  
AAAPOL.0002  
AAAPRO.0001  
AAAPRO.0002  
AAAPRO.0003  
AAAPRO.0004  
AAAXEL.0002  
AAAJOK.1111  
AAAJOK.2222
```

I only need the first occurrence using the pattern of the 1st 6 characters so I need to know how to check for the duplicate/uniqueness that will only match the 1st 6 characters.

The command should return this from the data above:

```
AAAPOL.0001   
AAAPRO.0001   
AAAXEL.0002   
AAAJOK.1111
```

I do not have access to the `uniq -w` option.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using awk

In your examples, the first six characters are followed by a period.  If that is always true, then:

```
$ awk -F. '!c[$1]++' File
AAAPOL.0001
AAAPRO.0001
AAAXEL.0002
AAAJOK.1111
```

This works by using `.` as a field separator and keeping track of the number of times that the first field has appeared already.

If that is not the case, then:

```
$ awk '!c[substr($0, 1, 6)]++' File
AAAPOL.0001
AAAPRO.0001
AAAXEL.0002
AAAJOK.1111
```

`substr($0, 1, 6)` is the first six characters of the line.  Associative array `c` keeps track of the number of times that we have seen those first six characters.  Thus, if `c[substr($0, 1, 6)]` is non-zero, we have already seen those characters and the line should not be printed.  In awk, non-zero means true.  So, we invert the test with `!`: this means that `!c[substr($0, 1, 6)]` is true if those six characters have *not* been seen before.  The trailing `++` updates the count in `c` before we read the next line.

#### Using uniq

For reference for those who, unlike the OP, have access to a version of `uniq` with the `-w` option, then:

```
$ uniq -w6 File
AAAPOL.0001
AAAPRO.0001
AAAXEL.0002
AAAJOK.1111
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind about the order of lines to be changed, you can use `sort -u` with the sort key set to those first 6 characters:

```
sort -u -k 1,1.6
```

Or to the part before the `.`:

```
sort -t . -u -k 1,1
```